# jQuery slider to trigger updatepanel

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm using this jQuery slider:

http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/

I use it's `change` event to slide it. 
I have a updatepanel on my page. And when I move my slider, I want to change values (shown on labels) in the updatepanel.

So is it possible to fire async postback to update the updatepanel on `change` event of the slider? I'm new to jQuery. So please help.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnRefresh" runat="server" Text="Refresh"
                            OnClick="btnRefresh_Click" />
<div id="slider" runat="server"></div>
....
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                            <Triggers>
                                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnRefresh" />
                            </Triggers>
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <fieldset id="fldMain" runat="server">
                                    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Width="100%" >
                                        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phMain" runat="server" ></asp:PlaceHolder>
                                    </asp:Panel>
                                </fieldset>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Update:

I tried with `__doPostBack('UpdatePanel1', '');` in `change` event of slider. But full postback is happening.

I'm putting the labels  in placeholder `phMain`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind the slide-event of the this widget.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider({
        range: "max",
        min: 1,
        max: 10,
        value: 2,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
        }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider( "value" ) );
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please elaborate with some sort of snippet? I don't have much clue about it.